# Cassandra Data Integrity

Tags: cassandra

What is the best way to maintain data integrity in cassandra? I am using cassandra as a primary datastore for an e-commerce application. The data are scattered across multiple column families after denormalization. e.g. If I have an "Items" CF as:

```
CF: Items
------------------------------------------------
       | itemName |  price  |  rating  |
ItemId |----------|---------|----------|  ...
       |   value  |  value  |   value  |
------------------------------------------------
```

I can have another column family to satify a query to get "all the items with rating 5". The query column family can contain the additional information about the particular Item.

```
CF: ItemsByRating
----------------------------------------------------------------
         |   itemId1     |   itemId2     |   itemId3     |
5 rating |---------------|---------------|---------------| ...
         | item1 details | item2 details | item3 details |
-----------------------------------------------------------------
```

I have a daemon running which gets notified of the changes in details of the "Items" CF and do the necessary update to the value field in the "ItemsByRating" CF. This gets complex when there are lot of CFs to serve queries for Items. Is there any best way to do it?

Comment: "This gets complex when there are lot of CFs to serve queries for Items" please elaborate on this.

Answer (score 2):

For this particular situation (querying items with specified rating) it's better to use secondary index on `rating` column in `Items` CF. Cassandra will take care of index update, and it will be much faster than any external daemon. Implementation of a daemon that provides integrity guarantees in cassandra is very hard, since it would require implementation of entire failover layer.

As for general problem (e-commerce site on Cassandra), I'd recommend to keep consistent data **outside** of Cassandra, for example in SQL database.

Even a large-scale e-commerce site barely has more than a million of items in catalog and processes more than few millions transactions per day. MySQL with master/slave replication can easily handle this amount of data. It is possible to design an e-commerce system based purely on cassandra that handles transactions consistently, but it would require various tricks, like distributed row locks or external locks with Zookeeper or Hazelcast. On this amount of data (millions of rows), SQL database will be faster, simpler and much more stable. Yes, it will have a single point of failure. But e-commerce application that is down is better than an application performing random transactions.

To build a truly scalable system, Cassandra might be used to handle data that don't require strong consistency, like page views: it's not a problem if a single page view event is lost, data is still good enough for data mining, machine learning, etc.

Answer (score 2):

There is configurable consistency in Cassandra:
docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.0/cassandra/dml/dml_config_consistency_c.html

But it is not the same consistency mentioned in ACID:
mighty-titan.blogspot.com/2012/06/understanding-cassandras-consistency.html

The main problem with Cassandra: No transactions. This specifically means "no rollbacks". Cassandra's theory is: most of the use cases do not overwrite the same data, and when they do, most of the time you don't need a full rollback:
http://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.0/cassandra/dml/dml_ltwt_transaction_c.html